# Reducing(Adjusting) Double/Float variable decimal points in swift

Tags: swift, double, decimal-point

I'm trying to reduce the decimal points of this simple function which return the probability of something, but I learned that I need to convert the Double to String then reduce the decimals and return the string value in the result view.

Is there any way to force the Double variable(or other simpler way) to show only 2 decimal points in the result with swift 5.1  ?

```
    @State var pairCount = 0
    @State var rollCount = 0
    @State var pairChance : Double = 0


     Text("\(pairChance)    %")

     Button(action: {            
                      self.pairChance = Double(self.pairCount) / Double(self.rollCount) * 100.0
                      })
```

Comment: Ever heard of [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)?

Comment: @Sweeper No, could you help with that, how should I implement it in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI’s text views have an optional `specifier` parameter that lets us customize the way data is presented inside the label.

```
@State var pairCount = 2
@State var rollCount = 3
@State var pairChance : Double = 0
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("\(pairChance, specifier: "%.2f")%")
        Button(action: {
             self.pairChance = Double(self.pairCount) / Double(self.rollCount) * 100.0
        }) {
            Text("Calculate")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't know this... Does this have i18n support?

Comment: @Sweeper, It does support i18n. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter):

```
@State var pairCount = 1.0
@State var rollCount = 3.0
@State var pairChance = "" // this should be a string, because numbers don't have a format. Strings do.

let formatter = { () -> NumberFormatter in
    let f = NumberFormatter()
    f.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    f.numberStyle = .percent
    return f
}()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("\(pairChance)")
        Button(action: {
            // here we format it
            if let formatted = self.formatter.string(for: (self.pairCount / self.rollCount)) {
                self.pairChance = formatted
            }
        }) {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Small optimisations: `formatter` doesn't need to be mutable and you can use `string(for:)` so that you don't need the cast to `NSNumber`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks. Edited.